# function does not pass the value

Tags: vba

please help me with this problem. I'm just starting to use VBA and after searching the forum was not able to find a solution. I have 1000 single digit numbers in my spreadsheet. 20 rows of 50 numbers in each. my program suppose to find the largest product. For some reason my final answer is 0. I've done some debugging and the program goes through all the loops and iterations as expected. I suspect that my function does not pass the value back to my main

```
    Public Sub problem8()

Dim product, i, j, maxproduct As Long
maxproduct = product = 1

For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 50
        product = calcproduct(i, j)

        If product > maxproduct Then maxproduct = product
    Next j
Next i
Range("AY1").Value = maxproduct

End Sub

Function calcproduct(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long

Dim i, j, count As Long
counter = calcproduct = 1
For i = a To 20
    For j = b To 50
        calcproduct = Cells(i, j).Value * calcproduct
        counter = counter + 1
        If counter = 13 Then Exit Function
    Next j
Next i

End Function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this is the wrong way to express what you are trying to accomplish.

```
maxproduct = product = 1
```

This says *"maxproduct is equal to False"*. *product* was just declared so it is for all intents and purposes a zero and not equal to *1*. You wanted to say,

```
maxproduct = 1
product = 1
```

If you really need to put those last two on a single line then use a colon like this,

```
maxproduct = 1: product = 1
```

The same holds true for the similar syntax in the function.

Now it is important to understand that VBA treats *True* as *-1* and *False* as *0* (*zero*). Since you are essentially initializing *maxproduct* and *product* as zeroes, you can multiply anything you want by it and you will still end up with zero. Again, the same holds true for the way this similar variable assignment was handled in the function.

Here is my take on your project.

```
Option Explicit

Public Const maxA As Long = 20
Public Const maxB As Long = 50
Public Const cntC As Long = 13

Public Sub problem8()
    Dim product As Long, i As Long, j As Long, maxproduct As Long
    maxproduct = 1: product = 1

    For i = 1 To maxA
        For j = 1 To maxB
            product = calcproduct(i, j)
            If product > maxproduct Then maxproduct = product
        Next j
    Next i
    Range("AY1").Value = maxproduct
End Sub

Function calcproduct(ByVal a As Long, ByVal b As Long) As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long, counter As Long
    counter = 1: calcproduct = 1
    For i = a To maxA
        For j = b To maxB
            calcproduct = Cells(i, j).Value * calcproduct
            counter = counter + 1
            If counter = cntC Then Exit Function
        Next j
    Next i
End Function
```

I moved the limits to public constants which make it easier to modify for different sized regions. In your function you declared a *count* then started using a var called *counter* so I changed that to suit. As mentioned in another post, the variable declaration needs to be specific or you end up with a bunch of variants and a few longs.

Comment: Thank you very much guys for your help, assigning product and maxproduct in two separate lines fixed the problem.

Comment: Is there any way to display intermediate values of the variables during debugging process. In C it is a valuable tool where one can spot a mistake immediately. Thank you

Comment: @amiros01 - Too much information to be passed along here in any reasonable sense but you can start here - [Debuggin Macros](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h9b001cb(v=vs.90).aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
Dim product, i, j, maxproduct As Long
```

to:

```
Dim product as long, i as long, j as long, maxproduct As Long
```

and:

```
Dim i, j, count As Long
```

to:

```
Dim i as long, j as long, count As Long
```

I used to think putting it on the end applied it to everything on the row but it doesn't and I encountered a similar issue to you.

I might add though, the way you have done this (assigning i and j to new variables a and b then using i and j in the second routine) is extremely confusing and I would strongly recommend against it.